# How to pass data from parent to child in Angular to change the background color of the child?

Tags: angular, binding, styles, decorator

I would like to pass `color` from parent to child. Then in child component I wanted to access the element itselt to change the background color as follow `this.element.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor === this.bgColor;`

But there is no change.

child component: event-thumbnail.component.ts

parent component: events-list.component.ts

//event-thumbnail.component.ts

```
import { Component, ElementRef, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { elementAt } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'event-thumbnail',
  template: `
    <div class="well hoverwell thumbnail">
      <h2>{{ event.name }}</h2>
      <div>Date: {{ event.date }}</div>
      <div>Time: {{ event.time }}</div>
      <div>Price: $ {{ event.price }}</div>
      <div>
        <span>Location: {{ event.location.address }}</span>
        <span>&nbsp;</span>
        <span>{{ event.location.city }}, {{ event.location.country }}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class EventThumbnailComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() event: any = [];
  @Input() bgColor: string = 'red';

  constructor(public element: ElementRef) {
    console.log(element.nativeElement);
 
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.element.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = this.bgColor;
    console.log(this.element.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor); //
  }
}
```

I am passing `color` and `event` from parent as below

//events-list.components.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'events-list',
  templateUrl: './events-list.component.html',
})
export class EventsListComponent {
  color = 'black';
  event = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Angular Connect',
    date: '9/26/2036',
    time: '10:00 am',
    price: 56,
    imageUrl: '/assets/images/angularconnect-shiels.png',
    location: {
      address: '1057 DT',
      city: 'London',
      country: 'England',
    },
  };
}
```

//events-list.component.html

```
<div>
  <h1>Upcoming Angular Events</h1>
  <hr />
  <event-thumbnail [bgColor]="color" [event]="event"></event-thumbnail>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `[ngStyle]` with the input you already have.

```html
<div [ngStyle]="{ backgroundColor: bgColor }">
  <!-- content here -->
</div>
```

It is an anti-pattern to put logic in a constructor, or to try and access anything using `ElementRef` except in very specific circumstances.

Comment: In the code, I wanted to change the bgColor of `<event-thumbnail [bgColor]="color" [event]="event"></event-thumbnail>` element. But I think it is not html element and has no bgColor attribute?

Comment: Technically it is an HTML element, so it can be targeted. You could use a Directive instead, but an @Input and ngStyle work just fine if you wrap your component’s contents in a block element.

Comment: It seems this is not working `<event-thumbnail [ngStyle]="{ 'background-color': 'blue' }" [event]="event" ></event-thumbnail>`

Comment: Is there any reason you're not putting a `<div>` in your `<event-thumbnail>` template as the parent element and putting `[ngStyle]` on there?

Answer (score 0):

3 issues that i'm seeing with your code.

1. in line `this.element.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor === this.bgColor;` you're not assigning the background color to the element, you should use "=" operator instead of "==="
2. your input of bgColor value won't be available in the constructor, only on OnInit which happens later
3. your background won't be changed after the init because it's setting your background only when it's getting initialized.

i would solve it by using ngOnChanges() as following:

```
export class EventThumbnailComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() event: any = [];
  @Input() bgColor: string = 'red';

  constructor(public element: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
   if (changes['bgColor']) {
    this.element.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor === this.bgColor;
   }
  }
}
```

anyways, this is certainly not the best way to achieve what you're trying to, I suggest that you'll take a look on ngStyle directive.

Comment: None of this is ok in Angular.

Comment: Accessing an element via its `ElementRef` is generally to be avoided. Plus you've baked in the same mistake you pointed out in OP's code with `===`.

Comment: agree, yet i was trying to reflect what was wrong with his implementation and not to refactor his code. added a extra note on bottom

Comment: I'm struggling to understand why you'd provide an answer that is distinctly bad code, simply to say "anyway don't do this". Suggest you consider whether this answer helps anyone.

Comment: Does `<event-thumbnail></event-thumbnail>` element have style.backgroundColor property ?

Comment: Technically yes. There are Angular best practices for setting it if you would rather not add a block element — in that case, you would either create a directive (making your code reusable) or use something like `HostBinding`. Both add unnecessary complexity if adding a `<div>` isn't an issue.

Answer (score -1):

Input setter is your friend.

```
          import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
        
        @Component({
          selector: 'app-name-child',
          template: '<h3>"{{name}}"</h3>'
        })
        export class NameChildComponent {
          @Input()
          set bgColor(name: string) {
                this._bgColor = name;
          }

private _bgColor: string = 'red';
    
      constructor() {
      }
    
        }
```

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#intercept-input-property-changes-with-a-setter

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: After edits, it answers the question, but using distinct Angular anti-patterns.

Comment: After more edits, this answer is getting further and further from anything even remotely helpful. This code does not achieve what the OP asked for, and doesn't actually do anything useful that a normal `@Input` doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Gil's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/71705766/11022022), but I would try to do it with css only.

In the parent component's css:

```
.child-container {
    background-color: #whatever;
}
```

In the child component's css:

```
:host {
    background-color: inherit;
}
```

Also take a look at scss for more advanced options, such as variables: https://sass-lang.com/

Comment: This doesn't allow you to set the color dynamically. This does not answer OP's problem.

Comment: You can use css classes and dynamically set the classes.

Comment: That only works if you have a class for every desirable color. Hardly the most efficient approach.